# Remove non HTML tags from string

Tags: php, string, dom, strip-tags

So i've get a string here (it's something random i wrote, the actual string can be anything and can contain any/all HTML tags):

```
$my_str = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p><i:f>hello</i:f><div>some other text</div><qe></qe>"
```

I need to remove all **non** HTML tags, so `<i:f>` and `<qe>` must be removed, but the rest must remain.

I am fully aware i could just use `strip_tags()` function and just fill in all the tags i need to be left (and that's what i will do unless someone provides a more elegant solution), because filling in the `$allowed_tags` flag with all valid HTML5 tags isn't the best approach.

example:

```
echo strip_tags($my_str, '<a><i><br><p><div><aside><h1><h2>......');
```

So any ideas on a more elegant solution?

Thanks.
Tim

Comment: Find a tool to parse the string into a nested array of 'tag' => [tagContents]. Then go through recursively and unset() any 'tag' which isn't a valid html tag. You'll need a csv of valid html tags or something most likely. Then rebuild your string.

Answer (score -1):

You can approach this as

```
$my_str = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p><i:f>hello</i:f><div>some other text</div><qe></qe>";
echo preg_replace("/(<\s*\/?\s*\b(qe|i:f)\b[^>]*\/?\s*>)/i", "", $my_str)
```